# Soap connection with Silex

Tags: php, soap, silex

I've tried to connect with API from here:
http://www.hrd.pl/wsparcie/api/nawiazanie-polaczenia/
with micro-framework Silex.

I've found on github that solution: 
https://github.com/Ibsciss/zend-soap-service-provider
I've made everything what is on Readme. I registered service like that:

```
$app->register(new ZendSoapServiceProvider());
```

And after that I've got blank page and my error.log says:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ZendSoapServiceProvider' not found in /home/stolarz/public_html/hosting-site/web/index.php on line 30

Can you give me some hint, I've really stucked. Is there another way to connect by SOAP with Silex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the namespace of class you are trying to instantiate.

```
use Ibsciss\Silex\Provider\ZendSoapServiceProvider;
```

Comment: I thought it should be in controller, where I want to use this service, but when I put it in my index, it worked, thanks!